# Multiple objects in BorderLayout regions

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, border-layout

i'm making a title bar, and i'm putting the title on the left and two buttons on the right. But if I use BorderLayout.EAST for both buttons, only the last one will be showed. Can I get both visible?
I tried using the JPanel but it's going to make padding/margin around itself, and i don't want that. I tried removing it using createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0) but nothing changed..

actually i like don't using jpanel, because when i resize my jpanel if there is not space enough for the title it becomes like My Tit.., instead if i put the button in the JPanel it doesn't, it's like there's something above the text..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried using the JPanel but it's going to make padding/margin around itself, and i don't want that.

The default layout manager for a panel is the `FlowLayout`. If you don't like the padding then get rid of the padding. Read the FlowLayout API for more information on how to do this.

Or you could use a `BoxLayout` in your panel. It does not add padding. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

> actually i like don't using jpanel, because when i resize my jpanel if there is not space enough for the title it becomes like My Tit..,

Every layout manager has to make a decision what to do when there is not enough space. Read the tutorial and try the different layout managers to determine the one the best suits your needs.

Comment: Right now i'm using the SwingLayout, but it doesn't make the text in the way i wanted to.